gpo to allow local standard users to install software on windows
I have one admin account and 2 standard user accounts on a local computer and not on a domain. For example,
User A -> (Admin Account)
User B -> (Standard Account)
User General -> (Standard Account)
Is there a user group policy setting that I can enforce logging in from the Admin account (User A) such that, only User B can install new software on it? If not is there a mechanism to achieve this. I don't want to put any of these accounts on a domain.

Users can install any software that doesn't require admin privileges.
This depends on the software installation, whether it allows you to
choose between installing per-user or for all users.
The first option shouldn't require admin rights.
Standard users can install any of these programs, for example Zoom and
Teams. I think that Chrome would be in this list as well.
A well-built software installation would only ask for elevation once
the user has selected the installation option "for all users".
But there is no solution or GPO policy that can help with a
software installation that asks first for elevation.

In that case is there a way to prevent the General User from installing any software?

I don't know of a method to prevent the installation of "per-user" software that doesn't require elevation. Portable installations which don't use the registry or protected folders are also not preventable.

I think I found the solution to do so. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-block-standard-users-from-installing/5be06588-592c-47fd-9ebf-a6f05903a083

According to the comments that follow the first one, it doesn't work. I think it's mostly old policies.
